# Rename all the files within a folder with prefix “Unix_”

Tags: rename

Rename all the files within a folder with prefix “Unix_” i.e. suppose a folder has two files a.txt and b.pdf than they both should be renamed from a single command to Unix_a.txt and Unix_b.pdf

Comment: I would call it a prefix, not a suffix.

Answer (score 16):

```
$ for f in * ; do mv "$f" Unix_"$f" ; done
```

Answer (score 8):

The [rename](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/renaming-multiple-files-at-a-shell-prompt.html) command can rename files using regular expressions, which makes it very powerful.  In your case, you could do

```
rename 's/(.*)/Unix_$1/' *.txt
```

Comment: ... and the pdf-File? :)

Comment: `rename 's/(.*)/Unix_$1/' *.pdf`

Comment: No need to capture, just replace the beggining-of-string: `rename 's/^/Unix_/' *.pdf`

Comment: this doesn't work for filenames starting with `-` which leads to the error `Unknown option:...`

Comment: @mcExchange , have you tried with `--` option? Normally, all standard utilities support the end of option processing option "double-dash". Just in case, there's also `krename`, and `mrename`. More with `apt search rename` if available, including repository source lists.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using [Zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) as your shell, you could also use the function `zmv`.

Add this line to your `.zshrc`:

```
autoload -U zmv
```

then you could run:

```
% zmv -W '*' 'Unix_*'
```

See [`man zshcontrib`](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=zshcontrib) for further information.

Comment: The more I read about zsh, the more I like it.

Answer (score 3):

With the `rename` utility included in the `util-linux` package (the one on dj_segfault's answer comes from perl), you could do `rename '' Unix_ *`

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Some of the other answers might be better however, if I thought that xargs deserved a mention since it is a very powerful tool (and on many systems):</strike>

In this particular you could do:

```
ls | xargs -n1 -I{} mv {} Unix_{}
```

**Edit:** Retracted per [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles)' comment. For this situation this solution should be considered only a hack due to the caveats as pointed out by the cited article. The other answers are much better. I still think that `xargs` is still a useful tool (I use it with `svn status` relatively frequently), but he's right, for simple execute some command on all files in a tree of directories, this isn't the answer and find is much better. (Leaving the answer since the I think the comment is good for people who'd make the same mistake).

Comment: [Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). `xargs` is actually rarely useful, especially now that `find … -exec … +` exists.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles that's a good article. Edited retracting my answer.