# changing name of some files in bulk

Tags: linux, centos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rename all the files within a folder with prefix “Unix_”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13147/rename-all-the-files-within-a-folder-with-prefix-unix)
>   [how can I rename multiple files by inserting a character?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33261/how-can-i-rename-multiple-files-by-inserting-a-character)

Is there a way to make a change in name of some files, for example to append name of each user to files that reside in his home folder that if they moved somewhere can find files of a particular user? I use CentOS 5.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
$ for file in *; do owner=$(stat -c %U "$file"); mv "$file" "${owner}_${file}"; done
```

You should use `stat -c %U filename` because `$USER` expands to current user, not to a file's owner.

A file's owner could change from one argument to other, hence `rename`'s based solutions might have to cope with `/e` modifier of [substitution operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) or be combined with some call to `stat`. That said, I don't consider this question an exact duplicate of [question 13147](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13147/rename-all-the-files-within-a-folder-with-prefix-unix/) as the prefix would be dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

```
for f in * ; do mv "$f" $USER_"$f" ; done
```

Comment: exact duplicate from http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13149/18275

Comment: yes, it is. helps to have an answer here for lazy ones. marking CW.

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in * ; do mv "$f" "$f"_$USER ; done
```

Comment: exact duplicate from http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13149/18275